# CSS: In-page link or "anchor" doesn't allow scroll to top

Tags: css, wordpress, scrollbar

When I use in-page links or "anchors" to reach a part of the page, the scrollbar doesn't allow me access to the content above -- even though it is there in the HMTL.

My site is developed in WordPress but I think the problem is more my CSS.

See the naughty
http://adanewmedia.org/submissions/#review

versus the nice http://adanewmedia.org/submissions/

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 92 of style.css, remove this:

```
#main {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Seems like a weird bug, or maybe you have a height set in some parent element to the `#main` div. Removing that style should fix it though.

---

Further inspection I found this (style.css line 96):

```
#main-content, #secondary {
    margin-bottom: -32767px;
    padding-bottom: 32767px;
}
```

This is where your issues begin. Removing this nonsense fixes your original issue, but changes up the style of your site quite a bit. If you want to remove the black sidebar/footer, do that instead of pushing the containers all over the place.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. The nonsense at line 96 was a solution I found to get #secondary to be the height of #primary (inside #main-content) but I'll look for another solution for that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried playing with your code, it seemed to be this line in your style sheet that caused it - http://adanewmedia.org/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child-ada/style.css?ver=3.9.1

```
#main-content, #secondary {
  margin-bottom: -32767px;
  padding-bottom: 32767px;
}
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with that.

Also: firebug is rendering the page very oddly - I'd try validating your code as if Firebug is struggling to render the page correctly, then browsers are also likely to throw unexpected layout issues.